# Estimating ground state energy of $n$-qubit $2$-local Hamiltonian $H$ with known coefficients

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-computation

> Suppose we have an $n$-qubit $2$-local Hamiltonian $H$ with known coefficients. The eigenvalues of $H$ lie in $[0,1)$ and can all be written exactly with $[2 \log_2n]$ bits of precision. You would like to exactly determine the
> smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_{\min}$ of H, corresponding to an unknown $n$-qubit eigenstate $|\psi_{\min}\rangle$. You are given (as aquantum state) an $n$-qubit state $|\psi\rangle$ that has a significant overlap with $|\psi_{\min}\rangle$: $\langle\psi||\psi_{\min}\rangle \ge 0.7$. Now please give a quantum algorithm with gate complexity poly($n$) that outputs $\lambda_{\min}$ exactly with probability $\ge \frac{2}{3}$

I know I should use phase estmating, but I have no idea about detail. Can someone give me some hint?

Comment: Your question is not about research in mathematics, not related to "quantum algebra" as that tag means here. You should try another site of the StackExchange (probably Quantum Computing?). Good luck!